Rigify tail can only moves in up and down direction
So I made a human meta rig, then adding a tail by using Rigify samples section. I made sure that I connect the tail to the spine to keep offset, and then made sure the rig type as spines.basic_tail as shown here. However, by using the IK control of the tail, I can only move it in up and down direction, and won't respond to sideways direction. How do I fix this?



In the Rigify Type panel, shift click on all three axis, then re-generate the rig.


Thanks for the answer!
